# Como utilizar groupBy com pd.Cut?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou tentando realizar um groupby com a função pd.cut(), mas estou tendo resultados esquisitos. Tenho as seguintes colunas:

```
    jul/16        Ago/16

 R$ 34.252,00  R$ 52.000,00 
 R$ 33.850,00  R$ 33.850,00 
 R$ 34.850,00  R$ 44.590,00 
 R$ 35.850,00  R$ 45.590,00 
 R$ 36.850,00  R$ 46.590,00 
 R$ 37.850,00  R$ 47.590,00 
 R$ 38.850,00  R$ 48.590,00 
 R$ 39.850,00  R$ 49.590,00 
 R$ 40.850,00  R$ 50.590,00 
 R$ 41.850,00  R$ 51.590,00 
 R$ 42.850,00  R$ 52.590,00
```

E quando faço o pd.cut() na coluna de Jul/16...

```
quartis = pd.cut(teste['Jul/16'], 4)
```

Tenho os seguintes quartis:

```
[(33841.0, 36100.0] < (36100.0, 38350.0] < (38350.0, 40600.0] < (40600.0, 42850.0]]
```

Mas, quando uso o groupby com os quartis encontrados, para aplicar funções descritivas na coluna Ago/16, tenho resultados esquisitos:

```
                      min    max     mean  count
Jul/16                                          
(33841.0, 36100.0]  33850  52000  44007.5      4
(36100.0, 38350.0]  46590  47590  47090.0      2
(38350.0, 40600.0]  48590  49590  49090.0      2
(40600.0, 42850.0]  50590  52590  51590.0      3
```

Como o máximo para o primeiro grupo, que vai de 33841 até 36100, está abrigando um valor de 52000? É como se os grupos estivessem sendo ignorados, conseguem me ajudar?

Comment: A resposta é: Vc está montando os quartis baseado em Julho, mas usando os valores de Agosto. Dentro do primeiro quartil de Julho (33841 a 36100), você tem, na coluna de Agosto, o valor 53000. Espero ter conseguido explicar.

Comment: Entendi agora, ele não está filtrando o de Ago/16 como achei que o faria.. Você sabe como fazer isso? Por exemplo, tenho esses dados categoricos de Jul/16 com ranges de valores, e gostaria que Ago/16 seguisse esses ranges, tem alguma maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Não entendi  o que vc quer fazer. Vc pode atualizar o post com a saída desejada para o que vc precisa?

Comment: Por exemplo, encontrei os intervalos para Jul/16, correto? Agora, eu queria filtrar Ago/16 com os mesmo intervalos, ou seja, se o primeiro intervalo é esse: (33841.0, 36100.0], queria que ele me desse minimo, maximo e a contagem, dos números de Ago/16, que se adequem ao intervalo proposto. Nesse caso, seria apenas 1 número, o R$ 33.850,00, já que todos os outros são maiores do que o intervalor proposto. Nesse caso a contagem seria 1, e o minimo e maximo seriam iguais. Consegui explicar melhor?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a solução possa ser usando o método [between](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html)

### Criando DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"jul": [34252, 33850, 34850, 35850, 36850, 37850, 38850, 39850, 40850, 41850, 42850], "ago": [52000, 33850, 44590, 45590, 46590, 47590, 48590, 49590, 50590, 51590, 52590]})
```

### Gerando quartis

```
quartis = pd.cut(df['jul'], 4)
```

### Imprimindo DataFrame baseado se Agosto está dentro do quartil

```
for quartil in set(quartis):
    print(df[df['ago'].between(quartil.left, quartil.right)])
    print(80*"-")
```

Para o exemplo de dados que foi passado na pergunta, a saída seria:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [jul, ago]
Index: []
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [jul, ago]
Index: []
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     jul    ago
1  33850  33850
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [jul, ago]
Index: []
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```